# Buffer Use Explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, caesar-cipher

I found this ingenious caesar cipher solution on codefights. I'm trying to understand what the buffer is doing here.

```
b=Buffer
caesarian = (m, n) =>
  "" + b([...b(m)].map(x => (n % 26 + x + 7) % 26 + 97))
```

Can empty strings concatenate with typed arrays like that?

Comment: Strings? Typed arrays? Where do you see those? Please show an example invocation and what you don't understand about it or how you'd have written it without buffers.

Comment: Doesn't the Buffer constructor create a typed array? I did not write this. I came across it and I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: This is a Node.js `Buffer`, right? you should use the Node.js tag.

Comment: @epiqueras [No](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating a Node.js `Buffer` yields its data one byte at a time. For a Buffer (with the default encoding of utf8) that contains alphanumeric characters, that's the same as getting each char's ASCII code:

```
[...Buffer("hello")] // [ 104, 101, 108, 108, 111 ]
```

`(n % 26 + x + 7) % 26 + 97)` is the Caesar cipher arithmetic over ASCII - I guess you're familiar with this part.

So, this chunk interprets the String as an array of ASCII codes and transforms them to their corresponding outputs:

```
[...b(m)].map(x => (n % 26 + x + 7) % 26 + 97))
```

You can initialise a `Buffer` with an array of byte values:

```
Buffer([97]) // <Buffer 61>
```

You can get the String representation of anything in JavaScript by concatentating it with an empty String, so `"" + b([97])` is the same as `Buffer([97]).toString()`. `Buffer#toString` interprets the stored bytes as unicode characters:

```
"" + Buffer([97]) // 'a'
```

Therefore the point of the outer `"" + b(/* ... */)` is to turn the manipulated ASCII codes back into alphanumeric characters for display.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Are you sure you can concatenate any object with a string? "Hello" + [0, 1, 2, 3]?

Comment: Yep. That's `"Hello0,1,2,3"`